# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of null

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that receives data via @Input() decorator about the group. My goal is to create a new array of objects during component initialization based on data from group array. Here is my TS component part:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import {Group} from "@models/group.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-group-admins',
  templateUrl: './group-admins.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./group-admins.component.css']
})
export class GroupAdminsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() group: any = new Group();
  users: Array<object> = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.group.users.map((a: { user: number; permissions: number; }) => ({id: a.user, permissions: a.permissions}));
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.users = this.group.users.map((a: { user: number; permissions: number; }) => ({id: a.user, permissions: a.permissions}));
  }
}
```

And here is my Group and GroupUser models (if needed):

```
import {GroupUser} from "@models/group-user.model";

export class Group {
  group_name: string;
  type: string;
  avatar?: string;
  header?: string;
  address?: string;
  date?: string;
  city?: string;
  about?: string;
  verify_status?: string;
  site?: string;
  phone?: string;
  email?: string;
  web_site?: string;
  industry?: true;
  directions_list?: string;
  users: Array<GroupUser>
}

export class GroupUser {
  id?: number;
  user: number;
  permissions: string;
  confirmed?: boolean;
}
```

Here is my parent TS component part:

```
group = [];
ngOnInit() {
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(() => {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
  this.groupService.getSpecGroup(this.id).subscribe(
    ((info) => {
      this.group = info;
    })
  );
});
}
```

And HTML part:

```
 <app-group-admins [group]="group"></app-group-admins>
```

So basically I'm trying to create users array via ngOnInit, but it throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of null` although everything works fine if I use `getUsers()` function. Any help woul be appreciated.

Comment: Is the group being passed? It says that it's null, so I'm guessing that at the moment `ngOnInit` executes, `this.group` is null

Comment: Paste your parent component and corresponding HTML where <app-group-admins> is used

Comment: Group is passed because `getUsers() {
    this.users = this.group.users.map((a: { user: number; permissions: number; }) => ({id: a.user, permissions: a.permissions}));
  }` function works. I'll add parent component part in my question

Answer (score 0):

why not use a setter in he input? -if you needn't group you needn't store in a auxiliar variable

```
  @Input() set group(value:Group){
    this.users=value && value.users?value.users..map((a: { user: number; permissions: number; }) => 
          ({id: a.user, permissions: a.permissions}));
        :[];
  }
  users: Array<object> = [];
  constructor() { }
```

Comment: It throws an error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Group'.`

Comment: sorry is `value.users`, just corrected in code. We can also check if has value

Comment: Sorry but your code is unclear to me, there are 2 dots before `map()` and I didn't understand this part `:[];`

Comment: I use the "conditional operator" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator. Its only say `variable=(condition)?valor1:valor2` that's, if the condition is fullfilled variable take the valor1, else take the valor2. In this case the condition is `value && value.users`, that's value must has any value, futhermore, must has a property 'users', and this property must has value

Answer (score 0):

`@Input() group: any = new Group();`

that line doesn't look right to me. you use @Input if you are passing something from a parent component to a child component, and shouldn't be re-initialized.

try this:

```
@Input('group') group: Group;
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.group);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for advice but the problem persists

Comment: well after changing your code to what I wrote, is group defined or undefined in the child component? if it's undefined, then it must be undefined in the parent as well.